# change a particular element inside array of json objects using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have the following json:

```
{
    "kind": "ClusterConfig",
    "managedNodeGroups": [
      {
        "name": "default-nodegroup",
        "instanceType": "t3.medium"
      },
      {
        "name": "elk-master-nodegroup",
        "instanceType": "t3.medium"
      },
      {
        "name": "elk-data-nodegroup",
        "instanceType": "t3.medium"
      }
    ]
}
```

The above json is a valid subset of a big json file with some other details, which are suppressed for brevity. Now I want to add an item `availabiltyZone: $PREFERRED_ZONE` to each of the array elements of `managedNodeGroups`. For example, I want the output to be:

```
{
    "kind": "ClusterConfig",
    "managedNodeGroups": [
      {
        "name": "default-nodegroup",
        "instanceType": "t3.medium",
        "availabilityZone": "us-east-1a"
      },
      {
        "name": "elk-master-nodegroup",
        "instanceType": "t3.medium",
        "availabilityZone": "us-east-1a"
      },
      {
        "name": "elk-data-nodegroup",
        "instanceType": "t3.medium",
        "availabilityZone": "us-east-1a"
      }
    ]
}
```

The jq command that I am trying and the error is:

```
$ jq --arg CONTR_CLUSTER_NAME "My-${StackName}" --arg CONTR_CLUSTER_REGION "${Region}"  --arg ZONES ${Zones} --arg PREFERRED_ZONE "${Region}-a" '.metadata.name = $CONTR_CLUSTER_NAME | .metadata.region = $CONTR_CLUSTER_REGION | .availabilityZones = ($ZONES|split(","))' | (.managedNodeGroups[] | .preferredZone ) = $PREFERRED_ZONE tmp.json 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `='
```

The `Region` env variable is set to `us-east-1`, and `Zones` is set to `"\"us-east-1a\",\"us-east-1c\""`, and `StackName` is set to `example`.

If I remove just the last part of the command and execute it, the command executes fine. So, it is the appending `PREFERRED_ZONE` to each element of the `managedNodeGroups` array that is causing an issue. For example, the below command, works fine:

```
jq --arg CONTR_CLUSTER_NAME "My-${StackName}" --arg CONTR_CLUSTER_REGION "${Region}"  --arg ZONES ${Zones} --arg PREFERRED_ZONE "${Region}-a" '.metadata.name = $CONTR_CLUSTER_NAME | .metadata.region = $CONTR_CLUSTER_REGION | .availabilityZones = ($ZONES|split(","))' tmp.json 
{
    "kind": "ClusterConfig",
    "managedNodeGroups": [
      {
        "name": "default-nodegroup",
        "instanceType": "t3.medium"
      },
      {
        "name": "elk-master-nodegroup",
        "instanceType": "t3.medium"
      },
      {
        "name": "elk-data-nodegroup",
        "instanceType": "t3.medium"
      }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ? I am missing some kind of `foreach` for iterating through the array element but can't figure it out from the docs. I tried with even `map, select` options but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jq filter shown in the Q has incorrect positioning of the quotation marks.

With your input data in input.json, the following invocation succeeds:

```
jq --arg CONTR_CLUSTER_NAME "My-${StackName}" --arg CONTR_CLUSTER_REGION "${Region}"  --arg ZONES "${Zones}" --arg PREFERRED_ZONE "${Region}-a" '
  .metadata.name = $CONTR_CLUSTER_NAME
  | .metadata.region = $CONTR_CLUSTER_REGION
  | .availabilityZones = ($ZONES|split(","))
  | (.managedNodeGroups[] | .preferredZone ) = $PREFERRED_ZONE
' input.json
```